# ActiveMQs doesn replicate messages between each other

Tags: ubuntu, activemq-classic, apache-zookeeper

There are 3 ZKs with 3 ActiveMQ's running on three machines. All of the 3 ActiveMQs are active (Network of Brokers). I have one Lead and 2 Followers.

now I have scenario if I send message to all three ActiveMQs only one of them receive message and other two doesnt. So it looks like there is no syncing between activeMQs.

If now the ActiveMQ which has message will go down than message will not be available. Is there any way to replicate that message to other two activeMQs before it will go down ?

Following config file for *activemq.xml*:

```
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="test" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}" persistent="true">
....
        <persistenceAdapter>
            <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb"/>
        </persistenceAdapter>

    <networkConnectors>
      <networkConnector uri="multicast://default"/>
    </networkConnectors>
```

and something wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 1):

ActiveMQ 5.x does not have a replication feature for server nodes.  You can get that sort of support if you switch to ActiveMQ Artemis which does support [HA and Replication](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/1.0.0/ha.html)